# Pandas: Subtract Date by factor until greater than another date

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

As title suggest, I want to subtract factor from the date until date is just less than another date.

```
op_d = {'ADate':[20200301,20200301,20200301,20200301,20200301,20200301],
        'MDate':[20520801,20531001,20550405,20540701,20540910,20510701] ,
        'EDate':[20200201,20200201,20200205,20200101,20190910,20200401] ,
        'Frequency':[2,4,2,6,12,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=op_d)
df['MDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MDate'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['ADate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ADate'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['EDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EDate'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

in the above data frame, I'm reducing months ('Frequency') from 'MDate' until it is just less then 'ADate'. Expected output is stored in 'EDate' field.

My idea is to take months difference between 'Mdate' and 'ADate', then divide it by frequency and remove remainder from 'ADate' which is a lengthy process.

```
df['tempDate'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['MDate'] - pd.DateOffset(months = x['Frequency'])  , axis=1)
```

Above code subtracts frequency only one time. is there way to run this in a while loop for each row or something like that? 
i.e.

```
df['tempDate'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['MDate'] - pd.DateOffset(months = x['Frequency'])  if df['tempDate'] < ['ADate'] , axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose a function, then apply:

```
def reduce(row):
    a,m,f = row[['ADate','MDate','Frequency']]
    offset = pd.DateOffset(months=f)
    while m > a: m -= offset
    return m

df['EDate'] = df.apply(reduce, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       ADate      MDate      EDate  Frequency
0 2020-03-01 2052-08-01 2020-02-01          2
1 2020-03-01 2053-10-01 2020-02-01          4
2 2020-03-01 2055-04-05 2020-02-05          2
3 2020-03-01 2054-07-01 2020-01-01          6
4 2020-03-01 2054-09-10 2019-09-10         12
5 2020-03-01 2051-07-01 2020-03-01          1
```